# How does the snapshot size affects restore process in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am doing some POC around creating a cluster from a snapshot. But I am uncertain about the time it takes to restore from an existing snapshot. Sometimes it takes around 10 mins but sometimes it also takes as long as 30 min.

Is there any data(size of snapshot) vs time breakup is available?
What operations does redshift perform in the background during the restore process?

Answer (score 1):

Redshift restore from snapshot does not require a full repopulate of data before the cluster is available.  Cluster availability is based on having the hardware, OS, and application up alone with populating the leader node (blocklist mostly).  Once these are in place the cluster can take queries and if the table data is not yet loaded into the cluster from the snapshot the restore of the data blocks needed will be prioritized and the query will run slow until these blocks are populated.  Since most queries are based on a minority of "hot" blocks the query speed for most will be as fast as usual fairly quickly.

I know this just complicates the analysis you are performing but this is how restore works.  I expect you are seeing variability based on many factors and a small one of these is the size of the blocklist table on the leader node.  How does the time for creating an empty cluster compare?  How variable is this?

Comment: When we create an empty cluster it doesn't take a fixed amount of time, even there is no data to restore.

Comment: Exactly.  Provisioning the hardware is not a constant amount of time.